# What is the apostrophe I see in HEP articles? (NOT antiquark)

Tags: particle-physics, notation, elementary-particles

I keep seeing references to quarks as q, and antiquarks as qbar, but I'm also seeing things like q' and q'bar. I originally thought it was another form of notation for anti- but it doesn't appear like it. I can't seem to find anything online explaining it.
(Example: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/color-online-Dominant-Feynman-diagram-for-t-t-production-in-the-all-hadronic-decay_fig1_50601354, which is figure 1 from this paper:
DOI:https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.82.032002 )
Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apostrophe means that the quark is light. A light quark is, in this convention, one of the four lightest quarks ($u, d, c, s$).

Comment: Thank you so much!